# read database table using read_baskets

Tags: r, transactions, sequential

I am using `CSPADE` function to mine sequential patterns.
I found that I must use `read_baskets` to read transactions before running `CSPADE` function.

My question is whether it is possible to read database table using `read_baskets` or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to export your data prior to reading your data in with a `read_baskets` functions.